# Получить родителя третьего порядка

Tags: javascript, html

Есть HTML кусочек следующего вида:

```
<div id='blockGiver2'>
    <form class='float_left'>
        <label>Представляемое лицо: 
            <select id="subjectDropDown2" onChange='insertValue1(this, nonclient);'> 
                <option class="grey">Выберите клиента</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

Как можно заметить в элементе  находится обработчик событий

```
onchange='insertValue1(this,nonclient);'
```

Который передает сам себя в функцию через this. Вот сама функция которая выводит в консоль ID корневого элемента DIV:

```
function insertValue1 (giver, array){

    console.log(giver.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id);

}
```

И все в принципе работает как нужно, но у меня пара вопросов:

1) Как правильно назвать элемент div по отношению к элементу select чтобы не возникало вопросов? Родитель 3го порядка? Родитель родителя родителя?

2) Можно ли переход на 3 уровня вверх записать как-то более изящно, чем конструкцией:

```
giver.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function insertValue1(giver, array) {
  console.log(giver.value, giver.closest("div.blockGiver").id);
}
```

```html
<div id='blockGiver2' class="blockGiver">
  <form class='float_left'>
    <label>Представляемое лицо: 
            <select id="subjectDropDown2" onChange='insertValue1(this, null);'> 
                <option class="grey">Выберите клиента</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
                <option value="4">Four</option>
            </select>
        </label>
  </form>
</div>
```